# Enabling CiviVolunteer 2.0 Volunteer Opportunity Listing

Tags: civivolunteer

How do I enable the public listing of volunteer opportunities for visitors to my civicrm website?

Comment: Has anyone enabled this on Joomla 3.x? When I use the links given above to make the volunteer opportunity listing public facing I just a get a 404 error. But I can see it in the CiviCRM backend administrator. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There's a link under the Volunteer menu "Search for Volunteer Opportunities" that you can copy to a menu option or a button:

http://address-to-your-site/civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/opportunities

You also need to make sure that the permission "CiviVolunteer: register to volunteer" is granted for the Anonymous role if they're not going to be logged in (or another role if they are).

There's some additional information at
http://civicrm.github.io/org.civicrm.volunteer/docs/

Note that Angular Profiles should be installed an an extension in the CiviCRM extensions directory and then enabled.

Comment: Thanks, Dan. I already had done what you suggested. I should have stated so in my post. I wonder if my Angular Profiles file has to be in the same folder as the CivIVolunteer extension. I'll check the documentation.

Comment: @ExecutiveDirector, the extension simply needs to be installed as you'd install any other CiviCRM extension. The org.civicrm.angularprofiles and org.civicrm.volunteer directories will end up being siblings beneath the CiviCRM extensions directory.

Answer (score 3):

The page for searching for opportunities is as Joe and Dan said: http://address-to-your-site/civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/opportunities

And I can confirm that Access AJAX API is a required permission. The new interface is built on Angular, and there is no way around allowing ajax permissions. See: https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer#self-service-volunteer-signup

I've consulted with the core team and there is no known security threat to allowing anonymous users to access the Ajax API.

Answer (score 2):

So I was having the same problem and could not find a valid reference.  In Drupal permissions, I extended this to anonymous user:

```
CiviCRM: access AJAX API
Allow API access even if Access CiviCRM is not granted
```

Can anyone else confirm that this is the appropriate fix? It works for me but I'm wondering if there are any negatives to enabling AJAX API access to anon...

Comment: Yes, this is the appropriate fix. Per the README (https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/blob/master/README.md#self-service-volunteer-signup), the following permissions must be enabled for users who should be able to access the volunteer opportunities search form: "CiviVolunteer: register to volunteer" and "CiviCRM: access AJAX API".

Comment: Re negatives to enabling access AJAX API: each API enforces its own permissions. In other words, if you have "access AJAX API" but not "create contacts," you can't use the AJAX API to create contacts. I think there's only one consideration: if you have Access CiviCRM or Access AJAX API and make an API call that you don't have enough permissions to execute, it'll tell you exactly what permission you lack. Some sites may not like having that amount of information disclosed.

Answer (score 1):

If your wordpress install will not show volunteer opportunities, i'd like to share that this did the trick for me:

/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/opportunities

instead of:
/civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/opportunities